# #Error thrown from `Switch` when string parsing in Access

Tags: sql, switch-statement, case, ms-access-2016, jet

I'm trying to do SWITCH statement in Access to parse GPS latitudes and longitudes of multiple formats into Decimal Degrees format

```
SELECT
  IIF(ISNull(a.Lat), NULL, Len(A.lat) - Len(Replace(A.lat," ", ""))) as _spaces,
  Switch(
    ISNull([_spaces]), A.Lat,
    [_spaces] = 0, CDbl(A.Lat), 
    [_spaces] = 1, CDbl(Left(A.Lat,2)) + CDbl(MID(A.Lat,4,6))/60,
    [_spaces] = 2, CDbl(Left(A.Lat,2)) + CDbl(MID(A.Lat,4,2))/60 + CDbl(RIGHT(A.Lat,LEN(A.Lat)-6))/3600,
    1=1, CDbl(A.Lat)
  ) as [Lat]
FROM AggregateTags as A
```

but that returns #Error for all except where `_spaces=0`.

So, I thought I'd debug by simplify the conditions, by only trying to parse where `_spaces` is 1 or 2. Further, in case my parsing was wrong where `_spaces=2` I thought I'd just put an arbitrary value for that condition. I also re-named the output result column, just in case there was any circularity in the references.

```
SELECT 
 IIF(ISNull(a.Lat), NULL, Len(A.lat) - Len(Replace(A.lat," ", ""))) as _spaces,
 Switch(
    [_spaces]=2, 50.0,
    [_spaces]=1, CDbl(Left(A.Lat,2)) + CDbl(MID(A.Lat,4,6))/60
  ) as Latt
FROM AggregateTags as A
```

This works for `_spaces=1`, but still throws an #Error where `_spaces=2`.

I tried `CDbl` casting `50.0` or `50`. I also tried to see if there was some issue with evaluation order by eliminating the reference to a column declaration from earlier in the query: `SWITCH(IIF(ISNull(a.Lat), NULL, Len(A.lat) - Len(Replace(A.lat," ", "")))=2, 50.0, ...)` but that still throws the #Error where `_spaces=2`. The same occurs when swapping the placement of the various internal condition + result pairings.

Oddly, I do not get the error when I leave off the `[_spaces]=1` and have simply the `[_spaces]=2` and a default condition

```
SELECT 
 IIF(ISNull(a.Lat), NULL, Len(A.lat) - Len(Replace(A.lat," ", ""))) as _spaces,
 Switch(
    [_spaces]=2, CDbl(50),
    1=1, A.Lat
) as Latt
FROM AggregateTags as A
```

Why is this throwing #Error for `[_spaces]=2` when `[_spaces]=1` is included also?

Sample data for the `lat` column

```
39 14.838
39 27 15.88
39.20628
"" (empty string)
NULL
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @LeeMac see edit

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Access is evaluating not only all of the conditions, but all of the calculations too. If this throws an error, even in a result corresponding with a non-matching condition, an #Error is relayed.  What a POS Access is sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Switch` statement in MS Access is prototyped as `Switch( expr-1, value-1 [, expr-2, value-2 ] … [, expr-n, value-n ] )`

Access evaluates ALL `value`s in the `Switch` statement, and if an error occurs in any - even if the `expr` does not match - it gives an #Error as in the following demonstration.

```
SELECT
  testing.ID as nbr,
  CDbl(LEFT(nbr,3)) as L,
  CDbl(RIGHT(nbr,3)) as R,
  SWITCH(1=1,999,0=1,CDbl(0)) as intval,
  CDbl(RIGHT(nbr,5)) as errVal,
  SWITCH(1=1,999,0=1,CDbl(RIGHT(nbr,5))) as first
FROM testing
```

Where the only value in the short text ID column is "123 456", this yields a result of

```
  --------------------------------------------------
  |   nbr   |  L  |  R  | intval | errVal |  first |
  | ---------------------------------------------- |
  | 123 456 | 123 | 456 |    999 | #Error | #Error |
  --------------------------------------------------
```

Obviously 1=1 is always true and 0=1 is always false.  Despite that, Access still evaluates both "values."

File another entry under "Access is dumb"

---

As to my parser, all my coordinates are in North America west of the Rockies, so all lats are 2 digits before the decimal pt and all longs are negative 3 digits. A more robust parser would find the positions of each of the spaces and break up the numbers accordingly, and may also look for and eliminate symbols (`°`, `'` and `"`).

Due to the craziness that is the evaluation method of `SWITCH` with respect to error generation, I switched to `IIF`.

```
SELECT 
  IIF(ISNull(a.Lat), NULL, Len(A.lat) - Len(Replace(A.lat," ", ""))) AS _Tspaces,
  IIF(ISNull(a.Lat), NULL, Len(A.lat) - Len(Replace(A.lat," ", ""))) AS _Gspaces,
  IIF(
    ISNull([_Tspaces]), NULL, IIF(
      [_Tspaces]=1, CDbl(Left(A.Lat,2)) + CDbl(RIGHT(A.Lat,6))/60, IIF(
        [_Tspaces]=2, CDbl(Left(A.Lat,2)) + CDbl(MID(A.Lat,4,2))/60 + CDbl(RIGHT(A.Lat,LEN(A.Lat)-6))/3600, IIF(
          [_Tspaces]=0, CDbl(A.Lat), A.Lat
        )
      )
    )
  ) AS Latitude,
  -1*IIF(
    ISNull([_Gspaces]), NULL, IIF(
      [_Gspaces]=1, ABS(CDbl(Left(A.Long,4))) + CDbl(RIGHT(A.Long,7))/60, IIF(
        [_Gspaces]=2, ABS(CDbl(Left(A.Long,2))) + CDbl(MID(A.Long,5,2))/60 + CDbl(RIGHT(A.Long,LEN(A.Long)-7))/3600, IIF(
          [_Gspaces]=0, ABS(CDbl(A.Long)), A.Long
        )
      )
    )
  ) AS Longitude
FROM AggregateTags AS A;
```